# C# Cannot connect mariaDB using MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Tags: c#, sql, mariadb

I am trying to connect to database called Symfony while using MySql.Data.MySqlClient. The database is Maria and i can connect to the server it is running on, but once i say "use Symfony" it throws an exception: User access deny. I contacted BD maintenannce and they confirmed the user permission is setup correctly on their side

Once I had a similar problem in java caused by windows authentication. Isnt that the same problem?

```
class MariaConnector
    {
        private string connectionString;
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private MySqlCommand command;

        public MariaConnector(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
            this.connection = new MySqlConnection();
            this.connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            this.command = this.connection.CreateCommand();
        }

        public bool EstablishConnection() {

                this.connection.Open();
                if (this.connection.State.ToString() == "Open"){
                return true;
                }
                else{return false;}

        }

        public DataTable Query(string query) {

                this.command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                this.command.Connection = connection;
                this.command.CommandTimeout = 300;
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                this.command.CommandText = "use Symfony";
                this.command.ExecuteReader();
                this.command.CommandText = query;
                table.Load(this.command.ExecuteReader());
                this.command.Dispose();
                return table;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Sadly, there is almost nothing good about that code.  There is no need to cache and reuse a connection - they ought be created, used and disposed of in the smallest possible scope.  Similarly, DBCommand objects are not reusable.  The `Query` method is dangerous because the only way to include parameters is to use string concatenation.  Such "Sql helpers" are usually more trouble than they are worth (and the source of a great many SO questions).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I have rewrited the code into scope with using(){} and got rid off the Objects. Now i still struggle to connect to the database. Do you have any experiance with such an issue? Thanks n advance